# Meteor autoupdate_clientVersion dependency.

Tags: javascript, meteor

I receive the following stacktrace when i start a initial Meteor project.

```
 Exception from sub meteor_autoupdate_clientVersions id pfs2yqG3gsT58Hhmx TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneOf' of undefined
 at Subscription.Meteor.publish.is_auto [as _handler] (packages/autoupdate/autoupdate_server.js:148:1)
 at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1711:12)
at Subscription._runHandler (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1026:17)
 at Session._startSubscription (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:845:9)
 at Session.sub (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:617:12)
 at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:551:43
```

The only thing i have done is meteor *{create app_name}
and started the app with meteor.

The error occurs when going to localhost:3000.

**These are my dependencies.**

autoupdate             1.3.11  Update the client when new client code is available

blaze-html-templates   1.0.5  Compile HTML templates into reactive UI with Meteor Blaze

ecmascript             0.5.8  Compiler plugin that supports ES2015+ in all .js files

es5-shim               4.6.14  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support

insecure               1.0.7  (For prototyping only) Allow all database writes from the client

jquery                 1.11.9  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors

meteor-base            1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app needs

mobile-experience      1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile user experience

mongo                  1.1.12  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP

reactive-var           1.0.10  Reactive variable

shell-server           0.2.1  Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command.

standard-minifier-css  1.2.0  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.

standard-minifier-js   1.2.0  Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.

tracker 1.1.0  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed meteor on my machine.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor
rm -rf ~/.meteor
```

(Uninstallation for Linux and Mac).

Then i installed it again.

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

(Installation Linux and Mac)